# How to display multi-line text inside a div, when assigning text to div using jquery.html() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to display multi-line text inside a div. I am using the jquery function .html(js string) to assign a javascript string to a div class named question. Inside this string I have used the 
 tag to try and break up the string once it gets assigned to the div class question.

I've tried using a few css classes, word-wrap and white-space to no avail. I've also tried assigning \n instead of the 
 tags to no avail either.

It cuts off the string where the first 
 tag is.

Any help would be tremendously appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```js
var question = "This car company <br> was known for their dent resistant doors. <br> Which turned out to be doors with a plastic outer shell. It is <br> also the name of a planet with a ring around it, and has now gone bankrupt.";

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.question').html(question);
});
```

```css
.question, 
.answer{
  /* display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content: center; */
  line-height: 13em;
  height:13em;
}

.questionboard, 
.answerboard{
  height: 15.1em;
  font-size: 2.4em;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: -1;
  border: 5px solid #000000;
  text-decoration: bold;
  background: #000066;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!--Questions-->
        <div class="questionboard" id="questionboard">
            <div class="question" id="question">This is just a placeholder..</div>
            <button onclick="displayAnswer()">Answer</button>
            <button onclick="back()">Back</button>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the line-height: since one line is as high as the div itself, the next line is actually underneath the div (you don't see it as it is white text on white background).

try this:

```js
var question = "This car company <br> was known for their dent resistant doors. <br> Which turned out to be doors with a plastic outer shell. It is <br> also the name of a planet with a ring around it, and has now gone bankrupt.";

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.question').html(question);
});
```

```css
.question, 
.answer{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content: center;
  height:13em;
}

.questionboard, 
.answerboard{
  height: 15.1em;
  font-size: 2.4em;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: -1;
  border: 5px solid #000000;
  text-decoration: bold;
  background: #000066;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!--Questions-->
        <div class="questionboard" id="questionboard">
            <div class="question" id="question">This is just a placeholder..</div>
            <button onclick="displayAnswer()">Answer</button>
            <button onclick="back()">Back</button>
        </div>
```

Comment: thank you for the explanation. I wish I could mark 2 answers..

Answer (score 1):

In your CSS you had **line-height** on **13em** which is a very large value I edited it to be **1em** the problem is fixed.

```js
var question = "This car company <br> was known for their dent resistant doors. <br> Which turned out to be doors with a plastic outer shell.  <br>It is also the name of a planet with a ring around it, and has now gone bankrupt.";

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.question').html(question);
});
```

```css
.question, 
.answer{
  /* display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content: center; */
  line-height: 1em;
  height:13em;
}

.questionboard, 
.answerboard{
  height: 15.1em;
  font-size: 2.4em;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: -1;
  border: 5px solid #000000;
  text-decoration: bold;
  background: #000066;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!--Questions-->
        <div class="questionboard" id="questionboard">
            <div class="question" id="question">This is just a placeholder..</div>
            <button onclick="displayAnswer()">Answer</button>
            <button onclick="back()">Back</button>
        </div>
```